# Filling an array with data from a .txt file, but a number that isn't in the text file is being added to the array

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I'm trying to fill an array with numbers from a text file. Everything is going fine except a number that isn't in the file is being added to the array. No matter what input file I use, the for-loop that I'm using to show what numbers are in the array returns `2.122e-314` or another extremely small number (depending on the input file) as the last element of the array. Is there an error in my `ifstream`, the `while(inFile >> list[i])`, or something else?

```
 const int MAXSIZE = 20;     

 void get_data(ifstream &inFile, int &amount, double list[]){
    char filename[256];
    cin >> filename;
    inFile.open(filename);
    if(inFile.fail()){
        cout << "The file failed to open.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    inFile >> amount; // gets the number of sales reports in the file
    cout << amount << " sales reports in the file." << endl;
    if(amount > MAXSIZE){
        cout << "There are too many different stores in the file.\n"
             << "Must be less than or equal to 20.\n";
    }
    else{
        double a;
        int i=0;
        while(inFile >> a){
            list[i] = a;
            i++;
        }    
        for(int x = 0; x <= amount; x++ ){
            cout << list[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

This is the data in one of my test files:

```
10
62458  81598   98745  53460  35678
89920  78960  124569  43550  45679
```

This is an example of the output I get from the for-loop that outputs the elements of the array:

```
62458
81598
98745
53460
35678
89920
78960
124569
43550
45679
2.122e-314
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping too far in the final loop

```
 for(int x = 0; x <= amount; x++ )
     cout << list[x] << endl;
```

reads one past the last element you write to. There are only `amount` items you have added. Change to

```
 for(int x = 0; x < amount; x++ )
```

to ensure you only print the values at the indices that you have actually written values to. It is quite clear from your output that your loop prints 11 values when actually you only insert 10 values.